# How to overcome maxClauseCount error when using multi_match query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have 10+ *Indexes* on my *Elasticsearch* server.

Each *Index* has 1 or more *fields* with different kind of *Analyzers*: *keyword*, *standard*, *ngram* and etc...

For Global search I am using `multi_match` without specifying any explicit `fields`.

For querying I am using using `elasticsearch-dsl` library, the code is bellow:

```
def search_for_index(indice, term, num_of_result=10):
    s = Search(index=indice).sort({"_score": "desc"})
    s = s[:num_of_result]
    s = s.query('multi_match', query=term, operator='and')
    response = s.execute()
    return response.to_dict()['hits']['hits']
```

I get very good result, and search is working just fine, but sometimes someone enters a bit longer text, and I am getting `maxClauseCount` error.

For example, search that raises an error when *search term* `term` is equal to:

`term=We are working on your request and will keep you posted at the earliest.`

Or any other little longer text raises the same error.

Can you help me figure it out maybe some better approach for my Global search so that I can avoid this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - this limitation is there for a **reason**. The more boolean clauses you have - the heavier search would be. Think of it as crossing (AND) or joining (OR) subset of document ids for each of the clause. This is very heavy operation, that is why initially it has a limit of 1024 clauses.

General recommendation would be to try reduce number of fields you're searching. Maybe you have fields which consist no text data or just have some internal ids. You could cross them out during multi_match query by specifying **fields** section explicitly.

If you're still decided to go with current approach and you're using **Elasticsearch 5.5+** and higher you could alter those by adding following line in *elasticsearch.yml* and restart your instance.

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count: 250000
```

If you're using **pre-5** version of **Elasticsearch** the setting is called `index.query.bool.max_clause_count`